# Invalid value for field 'resource.projects'; Google Compute

Tags: google-compute-engine

Invalid value for field 'resource.projects': 'projects/windows-cloud'. Resource was not found.

Getting the above error every time i try to spin up a win 2008 server vm ?? on the free a/c.

Answer (score 1):

In order to create GCE instances you need to enable billing for your project. Moreover as per [docs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/operating-systems#windows_server_images) Windows Server images are currently in Alpha, and require access to use. To sign up to use these images, fill out the sign up [form](https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/forms/d/1_U28LyQztpjlAwR43zNxX2V2bOzAfA3fGEeQ97KrXYM/viewform).

Comment: docs or not, either don't put it in the list of available configurations, or provide an error message that means something so people don't just think it's broken.